# Are there cases when I can mute last s?

Tags: deletreo, fonética

Just listening Manu Chao's marvelous song, "[Me Quedo Contigo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JMrxyv8B_8&feature=related)"
The question is - sometimes (not only in this song) it's sounds like last S in some words (ideas, ellas, siglos, ojos, labios etc.) is muted.

Is it a dialect or something? How widely this pronunciation is accepted?

Comment: I notice this often when people say "Buenas noches" and it sounds like "Buena noches."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's dialectal, but very widespread. In many parts of Southern Spain and South America it's common to omit the last "s". It's never correct in standard Spanish.

Comment: Oh, I see. Once again it turns out that reality is more complicated than it described in tutorials ) thank you!

Comment: In Mexico is not common to do it.

Comment: It is common in Puerto Rico & Dominican Republic. Also, this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_dialects_and_varieties#Debuccalization_of_coda_.2Fs.2F

Comment: I also heard this a lot in Venezuela.

Comment: When they drop the -s, this changes the preceding vowel, “opening” it up a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Caribbean countries barely pronounce the ending S at all, Colombians, Cubans, Puerto Ricans.

Manu Chao is quite a case. Since he (or mano negra / Former band) sings in French, Spanish, Portuguese, English and even in a dialect used between France, Spain and Portugal, which I can't remember the name.

Grammatically speaking, when you write it THE S MUST GO, there are no exceptions.